# Can't set readonly property on datepicker field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following code

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+10",
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        var max= new Date(dateStr);
        max.setDate(max.getDate() + 1);
        $('#ToDate').datepicker('setDate', max);
        $("#ToDate").attr('readonly', true);
    }
});
```

`ToDate` datepicker date is set properly and also looked readonly. but when i click on ToDate it's shows me the date calendar. which should not populated as per my need.

Comment: Going to need to see the HTML for `#ToDate`. Is it an HTML 5 input? Or a DIV with some library loaded? Is it a jQuery date picker?

Comment: You should use [`prop("readonly", true)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) to set Boolean properties on elements. Same issue as seen in [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](//stackoverflow.com/q/426258).

Comment: I have tried prop("readonly", true) but it's not working. ToDate is html5 input on which I have bind datepicker.